# Test doesn't pass in 8.20 railstutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

> FAIL["test_test_login_with_valid_information", UsersLoginTest, 2015-08-27 20:00:02 +0000]
>    test_test_login_with_valid_information#UsersLoginTest (1440705602.54s)
>           Expected at least 1 element matching "a[href="/users.762146111"]", found 0..
>           Expected 0 to be >= 1.
>           test/integration/users_login_test.rb:18:in `block in '
>
> 2/2:
>
> [=======================================================================================================] 100% Time: 00:00:00, Time: 00:00:00
>
> Finished in 0.46825s 2 tests, 10 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0
>   skips

Here's user_login_test.rb

```
    require 'test_helper'

class UsersLoginTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest


  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
  end

  test "test login with valid information" do
    get login_path
    post login_path, session: {email: @user.email, password: "password"}
    assert_redirected_to @user
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template "users/show"
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", users_path(@user)
  end



  test "login with invalid information" do
    get login_path
    assert_template 'sessions/new'
    post login_path, session: { email: "", password: "" }
    assert_template 'sessions/new'
    assert flash.any?
    get root_path
    assert flash.empty?
  end
end
```

User.yml

```
michael: 
  name: michael 
  email: michael@example.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest("password") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd double-check your header template and confirm that the appropriate code is there for the "Profile" link (listing 8.16) as that appears what's failing the test.

I'm not super savvy with Rails, but this part of the error has me a little concerned: `matching "a[href="/users.762146111"]"`. I'd expect that to be `/users/762…`.